# PHP function to draw several octagons centered at the same position

Tags: php, geometry, gd, polygon

I'm working on a PHP GD-based web app, and I need help with some polygon drawing.

I have a function that can draw an n-sided polygon. In this case, I am just interested in drawing octagons.

The simplified function looks like this:

```
function drawoctagon($ourimage,$xpoint,$ypoint,$radius,$color){

    $sides= 8;
    $points = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $sides; $i++) {
        $points[] = round( $radius * cos($i*2 * pi() / $sides) + $radius +$xpoint);  // x
        $points[] = round( $radius * sin($i*2 * pi() / $sides) + $radius  + $ypoint);  // y
    }

    imagefilledpolygon($ourimage, $points, $sides, $color);

}
```

//////////////////////////

I call the this function above this way:

```
drawoctagon($png1,$xpoint,$ypoint,$radius,$linecolor44);
```

But assuming I execute this line above 3 times, with all different radii, the octagons arent concentric...they are side by side, etc.

When creating the $points array, I added + $xpoint and $ypoint respectively, to move the drawn octagon from the top left corner, where it is created.

I hope I have explained this properly...but basically, my question is:
 how do I re-write this function to draw CONCENTRIC octagons, so that if it is called several times with the same xpoint and ypoint (as centers of the polygon), despite changing the radius, it will create octagons centered at the same spot.

Extra points for you if you leave the function still able to be tweaked for any n-sided polygon.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The center of your octagon with your function is

```
  x=$radius+ $xpoint 
  y=$radius+$ypoint
```

you can try to remove the $radius from the center expression

```
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $sides; $i++) {
    $points[] = round( $radius * cos($i*2 * pi() / $sides) + $xpoint);  // x
    $points[] = round( $radius * sin($i*2 * pi() / $sides) + $ypoint);  // y
}
```

and input the same `$xpoint` and `$ypoint` in every polygon you create.